# Склонение женских фамилий на -а, -я

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Склоняются ли такие фамилии, как Капуста, Лазука, Басалыга?

Знаю, что фамилии, заканчивающиеся на -а, -я, склоняются. Однако сами владельцы подобных фамилий часто настаивают на том, что их фамилии не склоняются. Может, есть какие-то нюансы?

Comment: Если владельцы настаивают - надо уважить.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В данных фамилиях А безударное?
Все фамилии с неударным А на конце склоняются независимо от происхождения.

**Подробнее и о других фамилиях на -а или -я:**

**13.1.11**. Наиболее сложную картину представляют собой **фамилии с конечным а**. В отличие от предыдущих случаев, здесь существенное значение имеет, следует ли а после гласной или после согласной, падает ли на эту гласную ударение и (в определенных случаях) какого происхождения фамилия.

Все фамилии, кончающиеся на а, которому предшествуют гласные (чаще всего у или и), несклоняемы: Галуа, Моруа, Делакруа, Моравиа, Эриа, Эредиа, Гулиа.

Все фамилии, кончающиеся на неударное а после согласных, склоняются по первому склонению: Рибера — Риберы, Рибере, Риберу, Риберой, Сенека — Сенеки и т.д.; так же склоняются Кафка, Спиноза, Сметана, Петрарка, Куросава, Глинка, Дейнека, Гулыга, Олеша, Нагнибеда, Окуджава и др. Все такие фамилии, независимо от происхождения, являются морфологически членимыми в русском языке, т. е. в них выделяется окончание -а.

Среди фамилий с ударным á после согласных есть как морфологически членимые, так и нечленимые, т. е. несклоняемые.

Несклоняемы фамилии французского происхождения: Дюма, Тома, Дега, Люка, Ферма, Гамарра, Петипа и др.

Фамилии иного происхождения (славянские, из восточных языков) склоняются по первому склонению, т. е. в них вычленяется ударное окончание -а: Митта — Митты, Митте, Митту, Миттой; сюда относятся: Сковорода, Кочерга, Кваша, Цадаса, Хамза и др.

**13.1.12**. Склоняемость-несклоняемость фамилий, пишущихся с **буквой я на конце**, зависит только от места ударения и происхождения фамилии.

Несклоняемы фамилии французского происхождения с ударением на конце: Золя, Труайя.

Все прочие фамилии на я склоняемы; таковы Головня, Зозуля, Сырокомля, Гамалея, Гойя, Шенгелая, Данелия, Берия.

Примечание. Фамилии, у которых конечной букве я предшествует гласная буква, в отличие от таких фамилий на а, членятся на основу, кончающуюся согласной йот, и окончание -а (Гамалея — Гамале'j-а).

Грузинские фамилии оказываются склоняемыми или несклоняемыми в зависимости от того, в каком виде конкретная фамилия заимствована русским языком: фамилии на -ия склоняемы (Данелия), на -иа — несклоняемы (Гулиа).

**Источник:** **"Грамота",а у них - Н. А. Еськова. Трудности словоизменения существительных.** Учебно-методические материалы к практическим занятиям по курсу «Язык современной печати». Госкомитет печати СССР. Всесоюзный институт повышения квалификации работников печати. М., 1990.

[здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?rub=rubric_482)

Comment: Да, у этих фамилий последний слог безударный

Comment: Ларf, этот текст, на который все ссылаются содержит некую недоговореность. Если на ударное я кончается иностранная, но не французская и не восточная фамилия (редко, но бывает - у немцев есть фамилии типа ВирлЯ неустановленного происхождения), её надо склонять? Я так понимаю, что надо, но в тексте об этом нет ничего. Ну и еще об односложных фамилиях (китайского, корейского или вьетнамского происхождения), которые тоже могут кончаться на а. Я знал человека по фамилии "Ба" непонятного происхождения, но вполне русской внешности. На практике мы эту фамилию не склоняли.

Answer (score 1):

> Однако сами владельцы подобных фамилий часто настаивают на том, что их фамилии не склоняются

Общее правило Вам дали вполне развернуто.

Некоторые нюансы есть. Они, правда относятся ко всему спектру фамилий, но коли уж речь зашла о них...

В качестве некоторого изъятия из общего правила о склонении фамилий на практике допускается несклонение или склонение по особой парадигме фамилий в тех случаях, когда регулярное склонение приводит а) к нежелательной двусмысленности при восстановлении исходной формы,   б) к фонетически невозможным или труднопроизносимым вариантам в) к неблагозвучию.
На деле такие случаи единичны, при этом носитель фамилии должен порядком потрудиться, чтобы доказать, что его фамилия подпадает под действие подобного исключения.
Где-то я приводил несколько примеров (пороюсь попозже), но там, кажется, нет фамилий рассматриваемого типа. За исключением **женских** фамилий типа Смородина или Жемчужина, которые вообще-то никакими исключениями и не являются, но о них часто упоминают в связи с неоднозначностью варианта склонения ([Завяление] Ирины Смородиной или Ирины Смородины).

И вот еще один спорный случай, относящийся, правда, к фамилиям другого типа.
[Склонение фамилий на ь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/20388/)
Честно говоря, я сам не знаю, как тут поступать, потому и задал отдельным вопросом.

Answer (score 0):

Также со школы закрепилось правило что мужские фамилии склоняются, а женские - нет. Так, если бы нужно было бы просклонять "Наталья и Андрей Мазура", я бы сказала Натальи Мазура и Андрея Мазуры. Из комментариев ясно только то, что придется доставать учебники.

Answer (score -2):

Женские фамилии не склоняются (ведь об этом был вопрос в исходном посте?). Значит, пояснения, данные выше, относятся к мужским фамилиям.

Comment: >Женские фамилии не склоняются   
  
Вас обманули. Вполне себе склоняются, если кончаются на Я или А. Иногда - и на Ь.

Comment: Меня обманули в средней школе в 70-х?! Этого не может быть! Хотя....
На днях познакомилась с мужчиной по фамилии Прохода, с ударением на "а", он тоже утверждал, что его фамилия не склоняется, и ссылался на своего школьного учителя....
Где же истина?

Comment: И все-таки...К примеру, женская фамилия "Король" - она ведь не склоняется. Так?

Comment: Женская фамилия Король, конечно, не склоняется.  
Но мы сейчас говорим о фамилиях, оканчивающихся на -а и -я. Посмотрите, как вопрос сформулирован. И в отношении них Ваше заявление о несклонении выглядит как минимум странным.  
  
Да и вообще, ни в какой школе Вам не могли дать подобную формулировку. Без оговорки, о фамилиях какого типа идёт речь, она вообще неправомерна.

Comment: Женские фамилии не склоняются!!! 
Меня этому научили в школе. Кроме того, читала (давненько уже) в журнале разъяснение на эту тему. Могут возникнуть юридические проблемы, если неправильно будут склонять фамилии. К примеру: Ирина Капуста и Игорь Капуста. Так вот, в родительном падеже "у И.Капуста" и "у И. Капусты" сразу становится понятным, о ком идет речь, о мужчине или о женщине.

Comment: >Женские фамилии не склоняются!!!    
    
"У Ирины **Иванова**"? Не бросайтесь усеченными формулировками. Они до добра не доведут.   
   
>Могут возникнуть юридические проблемы, если неправильно будут склонять фамилии.    
  
Склоняйте правильно. Проблемы - да, возникнуть могут. Но чаще - именно из-за неправильного склонения или несклонения там, где надо... Хотя с бюрократами вообще сложно бороться. Захотят придраться - придерутся.     

>На днях познакомилась с мужчиной по фамилии Прохода,  
  
Не вижу причин для несклонения. Чем он лучше Сковороды?

Comment: В исходном посте речь шла о фамилиях типа "как Капуста, Лазука, Басалыга", а не "Иванова", и я отвечала именно на исходный пост. Так вот, такие фамилии, как "как Капуста, Лазука, Басалыга, если речь идет о женщинах, не склоняются, если о мужчинах - то склоняются. Сейчас понятно, о чем я? И проблемы со склонением-несклонением могут возникнуть юридические. И бюрократы тут ни при чем. Фамилия Прохода ничуть не лучше Сковороды и т.п. Мужская фамилия - склоняется. Женская - не слоняется.

Comment: На каком основании Вы это утверждаете? Помимо слов школьной учительницы 40 лет назад?

Comment: Из того же источника, вполне надежного:

13.1.8. Склонение фамилий, оканчивающихся в исходной форме на гласные, не зависит от того, мужские они или женские.

Примечание. Материал Л. П. Калакуцкой показывает, что существует тенденция распространять соотношение, закономерное для фамилий на согласные, на фамилии с конечным а, т.е. склонять мужские фамилии, не склоняя женские. Редакторам следует всячески способствовать изживанию этой практики.