# Склонение фамилий на Ь

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

**Как склонять** [Иван; Мария] **Мышь, Карусель, Темя? А если пара** (Петр и Ольга Темя)?

Недавний вопрос о склонении фамилий подвиг меня задать вопрос, над которым давно уже задумывался.

Как должны склоняться мужские и женские фамилии типа **Мышь** или **Ночь**?
А **Любовь** или **Карусель**? Не такой уж нереальный случай...

На практике мужские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на **шипящий + ь**, склоняют по мужскому варианту (Николаю Мышу), что не всегда выглядит правомерным, а женские не склоняют, хотя бывает по-всякому.

Но это хорошо с шипящими... А вот если Иван/Мария Карусель?

И вот еще вспомнил. Иван/Мария Темя. Их-то как склонять прикажете?
Не "Ивану Темени" же?! Ивану/Ирине Теми? Другого не могу придумать, несколько вариантов забраковал.

*Дабы окончательно снять обвинения в надуманности.*

Реально найдены в сети:
Трубач Николай Карамель
Поэтесса Ольга Газель
некто Николай Темя
"Одноклассник" Иван Лошадь ("два штука")...

Comment: Вспомнил известных людей с фамилией на "ь". У Александра Друзя фамилию склоняют, а у его дочери Инны - нет.

Comment: С Друзем таких проблем нет. Там скорее уж можно обсуждать с ДрУзем/Друзём и ДрУзя/Друзя. *Как кстати? Я и не вспомню*. Да и с Друзь тоже, хотя боюсь, я не то что фамилию, о самом её существовании впервые слышу. 

Короче, фамилия Друзь никак не ассоциируется со словом женского рода. Как Князь, Витязь или Ферзь. Вот был бы они, не приведи господь, Грязь... Вот тогда бы и пришлось поломать голову.

Comment: У Друзя ударение смещается на окончание (ДрузЯ, Друзём). Инна тоже в "Что? Где? Когда?" играет, при желании игры с её участием найти можно.

Comment: Я очень любил ЧГК в 70-х, сейчас потерял интерес к телеверсии. Искать не буду. Остальное - понятно, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Вот что я когда-то скопировала для себя:
"*Фамилии, оканчивающиеся на мягкий согласный и совпадающие со 
 словами мужского рода или глагольными формами



**Мужская фамилия**

И.  Медведь Суздаль Тронь

Р.  Медведя Суздаля Троня

Д.  Медведю Суздалю Троню

В.  Медведя Суздаля Троня

Т.  Медведем    Суздалем    Тронем

П.  о Медведе   о Суздале    о Троне

****Женская фамилия и множественное число фамилий***: ***Медведь, Суздаль, Тронь"****.* 
**И ещё по поводу фамилии типа Темя:**
  Встречаются даже фамилии, ***созвучные словам среднего грамматического рода***: Блюдо, Благо, Долото. Несоответствие между фамилиями, совпадающими со словами среднего рода, и полом человека (мужским и женским), позволяет не склонять эти фамилии. (По книге: Суслова А.В., Суперанская А.В. О русских именах)

Comment: Спасибо. Источник не подскажете?  
Впрочем, это все вполне известные вещи. 
Если Вы видите в своем тексте ответы на мои вопросы, просклоняйте, пожалуйста, "мои" конкретные фамилии в мужском и женском варианте. 
Вот хотя бы Иван/Марья Темя и  Петр/Ольга Лошадь. )))

Comment: >Ой, простите, только сейчас увидела, КОМУ отвечаю.

Хорошо, я буду задавать вопросы инкогнито. ))) 
Тогда Вы сможете отвечать не кому, а на что. Это всегда правильно. Здесь нет ни страшилищ, ни авторитетов.    
  
>Женские не склоняются. Вопроса нет. Мужская фамилия на -мя также не склоняется.   
  
Может быть. Но вопросы как раз есть. 
Например (но не только): на основании чего вы решили, что Темя не склоняется. Чем она лучше фамилии, например, Дуля? Или вы вслед за некоторыми авторами предлагаете не склонять все подряд?

Comment: >Получается, что правота на стороне grumant: Петра Лошадя и т.д.   
  
Ясно. Женскую как предлагаете? И как быть с "Темя" в двух вариантах?
Вопрос о том, разве это вытекает из цитированного Вами текста, оставим на потом. Остальные случаи и примеры из Ваших списков, простите, банальны и к делу не относятся.    

> Получается, что правота на стороне grumant:  
  
А я его не особо читаю... Особенно, когда он в стадии "Остапа несло": "Женскую превращают в мужскую, и все в поряде". Расшифруете, кто его на такое надоумил?  
Нет, что так поступают, я сам написал. Вопрос, насколько правомерно.

Comment: Остапа несло. Дело как будто налаживалось. Представленный Еленой Станиславовной владельцу «Быстроупака», Остап отвел его в сторону, предложил ему крепиться, осведомился, в каком полку он служил, и обещал содействие заграницы и полную тайну организации.

Answer (score 3):

А что, если переставить на минутку ударение в фамилиях? Не Ло'шадь, а Лоша'дь. Не Те'мя, а Темя'. Вам не кажется, что склонять стало проще? Или это только мне так кажется?:-)

Comment: Кажется.  Тем более, что это уже предлагали, да сам я о том прекрасно  знал.   
Но вопрос так не стоит. Вопрос стоит, как стлонять фамилии с непереставленным ударением.  
Ко всему прочему, ударение в фамилии надо ставить там, там, где его ставит носитель. И если он возражает против перестановки, то об этом вообще можно забыть.

Comment: Тогда подскажите, правила склонения русских фамилий предполагают, что по любой из форм склонения по падежам,отличных от именительного, можно безошибочно определить единственный правильный вариант склоняемой фамилии в именительном падеже? Т.е. из Ирины/Ирине/...Теми однозначного ответа не вытекает, Ирина может быть и Темя и Темь. Наверно, логично было бы предположить, что эта фамидия не склоняется (подтвержд. комм. выше, хотя там правило звучит несколько по-другому). К сожалению, у меня нет никаких источников, только инстинкт. (очень возможно, что я сейчас изобрету велосипед :-)

Comment: >что по любой из форм склонения по падежам
  
Никогда не задумывался над вопросом в такой именно постановке.   
Подождите, дайте сообразить, правильно ли понял... Т.е. есть фамилия в неком падеже (доверенность дана Башмачкину А. А.) - и вопрос в том, ***всегда ли*** можно восстановить фамилию, как он написана в иметительном, сиречь в паспорте (Башмачкин)???  
Да нет конечно, как правило - можно, особенно если фамилия - русская, но далеко не всегда. Прежде всего это зависит от падежа. 
"Дана Голубе И. И." - Голуба он или Голубя? Или это вообще она?

Comment: А в другом падеже  - без проблем. "Доверенность, полученная Голубой/Голубей". А к чему этот вопрос? 
Сам по себе он, конечно, интересный, но него никак не вытекает то, как надо склонять - и надо ли вообще. К сожалению (или счастью) русский язык не всегда следует благому намеренью упростить жизнь тем, кто на нем говорит. Во всяком случаае правила склонения никак не вытекают из требования однозначного восстановления исходного варианта. Т.е само такое требование даже не рассматривается.

Comment: Уважаемый behemothus, вопрос (а вернее его автор) имел тайную надежду, что Вы сейчас авторитетно ответите, да,дескать, есть такое правило, и тут-то все и разрешится, но... увы! ответ не оставил никаких надежд, что, впрочем, тот самый инстинкт и подсказывал. А что касается перестановки ударения (см. выше), конечно, я понимаю, что с носителем не поспоришь, где ударение ставить, но вот, смотрите, рассуждение примерно такое, если имеются два слова (в нашем случае, это фамилии), которые пишутся одинаково, но ударение ставится по-разному, ->

Comment: ->то было бы логично предположить, что и при склонении по падежам должно соблюдаться это правило: пишутся одинаково, звучат по-разному. Отсюда предложение: переставить на минутку ударение в фамилиях. Лоша'дь и Темя' потеряли привычный смысл, и вот я уже легко склоняю их направо и налево. Вам нравится? :-)

Comment: Боже, natasha, я не задаю подобных вопросов, если наверняка знаю ответ. Я реально плаваю. Даже не знаю, что добавить. Про ударения уже  сказал. Все зависит от того, "разрешит" ли такую перестановку носитель фамилии.

Answer (score 1):

Если фамилия В.И.Даля связана с корнем слова"далеко",то вот пример:"... посвящённый В.И.Далю".

Comment: Вамилия Даля связана с голландским происхождением отца его.

Answer (score 0):

Ну в общем все свелось к ответу на вопрос "как склоняются по правилам", а не "как должны склоняться" (в сознании народном).
//===
Судя по всему, ответ состоит в том, что как надо склонять, никто не знает.
По одной фамилии отаета никто даже дать не попытался.

***Николай Темя. Ольга Темя. Иван и Марья Темя***. - как всё это склонять? 
И отдельно - "дети семьи [Темя]".

Честно говоря, ну уж очень хочется не склонять вообще, как и в случая с *Иваном Лошадем(?)*. Но ведь это против правил, так?

Хотя вру. Екатерина предлагала не склонять. Но уж очень неуверенно, судя по примерам только на оснований нескллонения фамилий "среднего рода".